# Thunderbird not displaying messages after second attempt with option --profile

Tags: email, thunderbird, mozilla

I have `.thunderbird` folder from a clone HDD.

I can open the mailboxes and my old emails by
`/mountpoint/home/username/.thunderbird` for the first time, but after the second attempt, all the emails and mailboxes disappears from the software.

The quickfix is to copy `.thunderbird` to `.thunderbird-new` and open the profile with the method above.

But then, now I have multiple inboxes named `Inbox-1` to `Inbox-4`.

I do not want to copy `.thunderbird` folder just to see one or two old e-mails every couple of months to fill certain application forms. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Make sure the file system supports linux permissions and permissions are properly set

Comment: the permission is correct. I know this because it works the first time I open the profile.

Comment: The problem occurs on the second time and onwards.